# Why does std::optional have a special equality operator for operand of the type std::nullopt

Tags: c++, c++20, stdoptional, equality-operator

The class template `std::optional` has the conversion constructor

```
constexpr optional(nullopt_t) noexcept;
```

So a question arises why is there declared the special single equality operator in the C++ Standard

```
template<class T> constexpr bool operator==(const optional<T>&, nullopt_t) noexcept;
```

when `std::nullopt` is used only as the second operand?

(See for example the C++ 20 Draft N 4860

```
// 20.6.7, comparison with nullopt
template<class T> constexpr bool operator==(const optional<T>&, nullopt_t) noexcept;
```

)

What is the reason of introducing this special operator?

Comment: Because [miracles](https://godbolt.org/z/noeseWzxx).

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you surprised that people would want to write `if (o == std::nullopt)`?

Comment: @BrianBi I am surprised that there is no operator template<class T> constexpr bool operator!=(const optional<T>&, nullopt_t) noexcept; or template<class T> constexpr bool operator==(nullopt_t, const optional<T>&) noexcept;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Looking at n4713, they used to be there

Comment: @Ranoiaetep No they are not, See the C++ Standard.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow see __4) rewritten candidates:__ in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution  _"..For equality operator expressions x==y and x!=y, a synthesized candidate __with the order of the two parameters reversed__ is added ..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten For example this program does not compiles.#include <iostream>

struct A
{
 int x = 0;
};

bool operator ==( const A &a, int x )
{
 return a.x == x;
}

int main() 
{
 std::cout << ( 10 == A() ) << '\n';
 
 return 0;
}

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Requires C++20 - live - https://godbolt.org/z/GbMzdKxj7 and sorry didn't notice the [C++17] tag on the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the C++20 draft. Drafts no later than [N4820](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/main/papers/n4820.pdf) had all the equality operators. They were later removed [likely] because of the introduction of [rewritten candidates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Call_to_an_overloaded_operator).